# No options for Data Export and Advanced Options gives unhandled exception

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using version 8.0.28 (build 1474738 CE 64 bit), I find that I have no object explorer for my Data Export wizard, and clicking Advanced Options throws an error stating...

Unhandled exception: "WbAdminExport" object has no attribute "options_tab".

Check the log for more details. I've uninstalled and installed again many times. I'm using Windows 10 Professional with all the latest patches as of the time of creation. MySQL CLI works fine.

Checking the log gives the following:

> 13:11:03 [ERR][       pymforms]: Unhandled exception in Python code:
> 13:11:08 [ERR][         python]: Error forwarding notification to
> Python Traceback:   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0
> CE\workbench\notifications.py", line 35, in _the_observer
> for obs, nam, obj in self.observers:   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\Python\Lib\traceback.py", line 121,
> in format_exception
> type(value), value, tb, limit=limit).format(chain=chain))   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0
> CE\Python\Lib\traceback.py", line 476, in **init**
> if (exc_value and exc_value.**cause** is not None NameError: 'str' object has no attribute '**cause**'

[image: A screenshot of the exception]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same thing happened to me when I did a version update to 8.0.29. What I did was (windows) go to the user folder "\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench" and delete all the content (with the program closed). When I opened it again I no longer had the connections (I had to reconfigure them) but I already had the data exporter working.

Comment: You can click on Tools -> Configuration -> Backup Connections and then restore them after clearing Workbench folder, however passwords will need to be re-entered and saved.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error when trying to export data from the schema. Basically, what I was trying to do is create a .sql script that I can run and will create a database schema with all the tables. I found an alternative way of doing this using the steps below:

1. Click on the Database menu
2. Click on the Reverse Engineer... from the dropdown list. The Reverse Engineer Database window will pop up.

[image]

3. Click on the Next button till you are able to get to the Results step from the tasks and click on close. This will generate the EER Diagram
4. Click on the File menu and hover over Export from the dropdown list. Select the Froward Engineer SQL CREATE Script... from Export. The Forward Engineer SQL Script window will pop up.[image]
5. Output SQL Script File field allows the naming and directory to save the script. Also, select the necessary SQL Options from the list. Click on the Next button till the image below and click on the Finish button to generate the SQL script in the specified directory.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I literally cannot even view the windows or tabs containing certain options like export

Answer (score 1):

The same issue on Ubuntu 21.04.
How i solved this:
Issue comes from mysqldump(console app) config files access rights. Only root(Administrator in Windows) should have write access to this file(s). If not, mysqldump will return warning like this:

```
$ mysqldump -V
mysqldump: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf' is ignored.
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

MySQL Workbench crashes, because it is not able to get mysqldump version.

Comment: Not the answer sorry.  Typing mysqldump -V returns no warning on either my local machine or the server I am connecting to.

Answer (score 1):

I had this behavior when upgrading mysql from 5.7 to 8.0.  I was on a Mac, using homebrew, but the key was with how in my MySQL Workbench settings (under Administration), I had specified the path to the mysqldump Tool as:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqldump
```

There was also an additional versionless path that I could have used:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqldump
```

If I had used that versionless path, I wouldn't have had a problem when I upgraded my MySQL version.  It would have just been pointing to the new version. So removing the version fixed it.  I did the same for "Path to mysql Tool".

I'm guessing a similar solution would work on Windows, but even if there is no versionless path, you'd at least have to change the path to the tools from the new version.